# Apache-test page issues with virtual host

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

i have configured Virtual host in  in apache with the followed tags.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot "/usr/doc"
ServerName www.example.com
ErrorLog "/usr/doc/example_error_log"
CustomLog "/usr/doc/example-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working fine when I try to access www.example.com with the respective index page.
But localhost is not giving the test page, instead it's giving the same www.example.com's index page.

How to get the default localhost's index page?